# C environment for learning the sufficiently hard way

Tags: c, windows, gcc, compiler-construction

I'm new to C(coming from Java, so I'm not learning programming for the first time). I'm reading the book, "C Primer Plus". I've been searching around to understand the differences between compilers or environments to develop C programs on Windows.

I have installed MinGW and Visual Studio 2010. I have tested compiling a hello world on both environments. For MinGW, I'm considering Code::Blocks or vim. The multi compiler support on Code::Blocks sounds convenient, but I'm not at that level to comprehend how helpful this feature would be.

I'm willing to learn C the way I should be instead of being spoiled by letting the works done background hidden by IDE like Visual Studio. Once I improve my understanding, I don't mind switching to a more convenient environments.

The reason I feel uncomfortable with Visual Studio is that it doesn't support the standards as much as gcc. I have read an argument that VS is used widely in production and that this is just the way it is. Some people say just start writing C wherever which is what I don't want. I've seen some say experience the command prompt and see how the linking is done, etc.

This is from Wikipedia, but it says that Visual C++ shouldn't be used for compiling C. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#Issues

So here is what I need to make clear. It might be a few blocks.

My understanding is that Visual Studio is appropriate as long as I'm developing for Windows platform and also good for people who just want to start coding.

If I want to go with the more up-to-date standards and use gcc (which is used in Linux), I should go for MinGW. MinGW is the minimum gcc-like environment ported to Windows, so I can use the similar environment to Linux which benefits me for the standards better supported than VS. Also, this is supposed to help my program to be compiled more successfully on Linux and not exactly for compiling a program on Windows MinGW to run on Linux, right?

The portability we talk about is compiling a source code on each platform and not to compile a program on one particular platform to use the executed file on other platforms, correct?

Comment: Visual C++ is *not* a C compiler, so there isn't really any question left...

Comment: As you are new to C, I would suggest to forget about portability, cross-compilation and MinGW. Just get a linux and vim and gcc. first, get going with native platform then think about platform agnostic behaviors.

Comment: @KerrekSB: VC does compile C code, so why not call it a C compiler.

Comment: The disadvantage of MSVC for C compilation is that it is a C89 compiler, and does not support the old C99 standard, let alone the current (2011) standard.

Comment: If you just want to get your feet wet Visual C++ is perfectly adequate (standards compliance notwithstanding).  You can compile and link from the command line to get a better understanding of what happens when you use the IDE.  Other toolchains will have similar semantics, so I'm not really sure what you're asking.  I would advise you to get a firm grip on the basics before worrying about cross-platform and standards compliance issues, and Visual C++ is fine for that.

Comment: @Icarus3 I'm on Windows. I just installed Code::Blocks. I'm gonna start writing code. Thanks.

Comment: @Luke True, I guess I can't worry about these issues more than this. I think I worried enough as a starter. I will start learning C and I should gain a better understanding of what these issues would become for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst Visual C++ isn't a C compiler, the Visual studio tools do allow compiing C code - the compiler under the Visual Studion is what is used to compile almost all of Microsofts C code (and there is A LOT of C code in a Microsoft Windows system, even if a fair chunk of the newer tools may be C, the basis for a lot of things is still C). You just have to ensure that you compile C as C, not as C++, since C++ has slightly different flavours of some things - some things that are allowed in C aren't in C++.

The way to do that is to call the file something.c, rather than something.cpp - it REALLY is that easy.

gcc is also a very competent compiler, absolutely no doubt about that. And using the tools in Code::Blocks etc will be a good way to learn.

I would actually say that Visual studio is definitely a smoother, slicker environment, and you can still use command-line tools like make to build things if you like - the compiler isn't part of the IDE, it's just a nicely integrated IDE. Learning a computer language should have as few obstacles as possoible. Making life hard for yourself is no help.

I personally use (x)emacs and gcc on Linux, but the first time I programmed in C, there wasn't even a proper standard for it, and computers typically had 8- or 16-bit processors - our school computer in 1985 had 2MB of ram and 3 disks of 64MB each (131000 something blocks of 512byte). That machine had 8 terminals in my school, 8 more terminals in another school, and the main school where the actual computer was had two rooms with, I think 16 terminals in each. So we sometimes shared the machine between 30 people!

Comment: +1 on what Mats said regarding Visual C++. It's really hard to beat the Microsoft IDE on Windows. There's really not much in C99 that is that groundbreaking from the older standards. I also encourage people writing pure C code to use .cpp file extensions and compile as C++, such that you get better type checking warnings and errors.

Comment: I have to disagree with the "compile C as C++" suggestion. Yes, it gives better typechecking, which is a good thing, but most compilers these days give warnings for type inconsistencies that C++ would detect. (and if you enable "Warnings treated as errors", they become errors). Chances are if you start using C++ to compile C, you'll do things that aren't valid C, and then you "learn bad habits".

Comment: To tell the truth, I was scared about VS. Now I feel like I was worrying too much of something I can't see, yet. Though I will go with the Code::Blocks for now. Thanks.

Comment: THat's like saying "I can't see the engine working in my car, so I'm afraid to drive it". YOu don't need that - you need some dials and lights on the dashboard. The rest takes care of itself if you know how to use the controls. And that's what learning C is about. The compiler isn't not the part you need to worry about - unless you actually start reading the source code in gcc [which is a bit like someone who can't read starting with "The Complete WOrks of Shakespeare" - which isn't a workable solution], you won't know more about what the compiler does in Code::Blocks than in Visual Studio.

Comment: I wanted to at least make effort to set myself to an appropriate place to start. I don't want to learn to code having too much of uncertainty. I have seen both good and bad comments about VS. My impression of VS was like, "easy and good to start", but "Not the best in terms of completeness". I might switch to VS later on. I'm glad I asked this question here because now I feel comfortable starting. This comparison might be way off, but I would hate to start HTML on Dreamweaver instead of hand-coding. Thank you Mats.

Comment: Yes, your comparison is way off between DreamWeaver and HTML and Visual Studio and C. In Visual Studio, you write C and press F7 [from memory] to compile it. Using xemacs and gcc, you write C and find a command prompt and type `gcc -o myprog myprog.c` to compile it. If you prefer to do that with visual studio you can, just open the "Visual Studio command prompt" shortcut installed, and type `cl -o myprog myprog.c` and it will do exactly the same thing - it gives slightly different error messages at times, but that's about it. However, pressing one key to compile is much easier.

Comment: I see. What I wanted to express there is that feeling you would get for missing the stuff I could learn that could be buried by new tools. However if there is no such a thing to this, then my doubt is solved now.

Comment: I don't see anything that would be "hidden", indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You should choose whatever platform that feels the most comfortable to you, and wait with worrying about the complications of cross platform portability etc. Coming from Java you'll get your hands full with pointers and the like in the beginning, so focus on that instead of the environment.

If you have written Java in an Eclipse environment before, the CDT plugin for C/C++ might be the way to go. It does among others support the gcc tool chain.

Regards

Comment: To do C under windows Eclipse is a good choice if used along with the Cygwin (gcc) tool chain. You'll be getting around using VC this way. @awonderer

Comment: I'm convinced to stop worrying about the starting place. Your answer is very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're gonna compile for Windows, try CodeBlocks, Dev-CPP or Eclipse as they all use GCC i think. Essentially you want something that **doesn't** force you to make a new solution/include a new project / make a new file just so you could test a few functions out. You want to compile a single .c file and run it, and play in that format.

If you're gonna compile for Linux, try Geany, Eclipse or just use gcc. Might as well pick up makefiles while you're at it.

Apart from that, write C code, or look where some of those public native java calls end up. But don't look at the math package, you'll be disappointed.

EDIT: just noticed your portability. Yes, you need to recompile on every target, or use a cross-compiler.

But cross-compiling is not enough, one must write code for different platforms too, say in Windows you will use the Win API call CreateThreadA(), but in a linux-build you will probably use pthread_create(). You should get familiar with using

```
//some code
#ifdef __platform_windows
   //windows code here
#endif
#ifdef __platform_linux
   //linux code here
#endif
//crossplatform code
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining portability. That helped to improve my understanding.

Comment: Somewhat being a Java guy myself, I feel your pain ;)

Comment: Heheh I'm looking forward to learn C :) Thanks Shark.